# Supply stdin input to subprocess.Popen() after execution of the process had begun ( and before it had finished )

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm making a program with a remote shell utility in Python3, using sockets and subprocess. Everything works perfectly so far but i have encountered an issue i can't find the solution for. Here is the code on my server script which executes a command received from the client:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(client_buffer.decode('utf-8').split(), stdout = subprocess.PIPE) # Creating a process
        while True: # Reading and sending the stdout from the process in realtime
            shell_output = process.stdout.readline() # Read a line from stdout
            return_code = process.poll()
            print(shell_output)
            print(return_code)
            if shell_output.decode('utf-8') == '' and return_code is not None: 
                #print("Process execution complete. Sending user prefix")
                send(client, ("<#" + color.user + getpass.getuser() + color.endc + "@" + color.dir + cwd() + color.endc + ">").encode('utf-8'))
                break
            elif shell_output: 
                # Process execution incomplete, signaling to client with code 2
                send(client, int_to_bytes(2))
                # And sending the next line of stdout
                send(client, shell_output)
```

All works well and i was satisfied, but there is one limitation that i can't figure out how to remove.
Namely, i can easily supply the server with a command with arguments and the server will execute it and send the output back, that works well, but if the program started by the command asks for additional input (for example a "(y/n)" question) before the execution of the process is over (mid-execution), i do not know how to supply the input to the process.

Can i do this with subprocess.Popen()? Any clue will be helpful and i thank You in advance. I forgot to add, the program is meant to be used in Linux.

*P.S Any functions and variables of which definitions/declarations i haven't provided in the code sample are irrelevant, but the project can be found on my [github](https://github.com/cz-czan/netcat) incase anyone wants to see more of the code*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I think `readline()` is problematic here, unless the prompt from the program ends in a newline(): the program writes a prompt and is waiting for an answer while `readline()` is waiting for an end-of-line. I think you're going to have to use `read()` instead and do things a bit more low level.

To actually send something to the program, I think you can just write to `process.stdin`.

Have a look at pexpect (https://pexpect.readthedocs.io). I'm not sure it fits your use case, but if it does it can make life easier so it's worth the effort to find out.

One other thing to consider: many commands have an option to make it work without extra prompts, to prevent the problem you're having when run from another program. If that's the case with the program you're using, that would be by far the easiest solution.

Comment: +1 I think this better accomplishes what **@czyngis** is really looking for and seems to answer all the different pains they'll encounter, especially with pexpect (thought it has some pains they'll share, such as [occasionally missing output and bonus characters](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/commonissues.html)) .. really, picking all the CLI args to begin with and running to completion seems almost-always better (even if this involves wrapping with a wizard which just asks the user for their inputs before really doing the run)

Answer (score 1):

By providing the `stdin` arg, you can access the [subprocess'd processes' `stdin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin)

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
    ...
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    ...
)

p.stdin.write("foo")
```

You can also just send the input to `myprocess.communicate()`, but it will then block until completion!

```py
...
stdout, stderr = p.communicate(myinput)
```

You can send a large amount of inputs to answer many questions if you know what they will be in advance (such as a friendly `"y\n" * 100`)

Comment: I actually wasn't aware it was directly possible when I started writing an answer (I've written a good amount of interaction code and seen some use logic like the [3rd-party interact module](https://pypi.org/project/interact/) ), but it seems to be that you can directly write to the Popen process object's `stdin` as long as the arg was provided during creation in addition to leveraging `communicate()` (which is thankfully all I've had to manage)

Comment: I'll check this code as soon as i can, didn't expect such a quick response, tomorrow evening i'll sit down and try this and mark your question as correct if it does work like this. I've got no idea how this could have evaded me, should have read the docs more diligently before starting work. Seems like exactly what i'm looking for (the first method of course)

Comment: Beware dragons. Very easy to deadlock using proc.stdin.write directly. Consider using a  [pseudo tty](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pty.html) instead.

Comment: Dragons indeed .. and that's really what `pexpect` (as suggested by **@Roel Schroeven** in another answer) [does under the hood](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/blob/master/pexpect/pty_spawn.py)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all obvious and trivial mistake:

```
shell_output = process.stdout.readline()
```

NO!!! You can only write to the standard input and read from the standard input.

```
stdout = standard output
stdin = standard input
```

View piping as real pipes.  The **output** flows in the
**input** of the other command.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?